# Building Password Validation Regex Dynamically

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm working on some legacy code, found a regex and was hoping someone could dissect it for me:

```
((?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,})
```

I know what it's doing, but not entirely sure how it's doing it. What exactly is the "." doing after the conditions?

I'm trying to add some code to generate this regex dynamically. That is, if a bunch of configuration says the password can do anything, I want to return a regex **that will return true for ALL CALLS OF .matches() in groovy.** So far I've just done string formatting, so the regex created is "(.)", however this is returning false when called with matches().

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `.` will match exactly 1 character which isn't a newline character.  If you want to allow any number of those characters (including empty string) then you'll want `.*`, one or more `.+`, exactly x `.{x}`, between x and y `.{x,y}`, at least x `.{x,}` or at most x `.{,x}`.  I'd suggest visiting rexegg.com (link in my answer below) and going through the information there; sounds as though you'll be back here a lot if you don't get at least a basic handle on regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation broken down for you and a couple example strings.

http://regex101.com/r/oZ6dK4

the tl;dr here, is using the lookahead assertions, it's requiring that at least somewhere in the string you have:

- a lowercase letter `[a-z]`
- an uppercase letter `[A-Z]`
- a NON-letter `[^a-zA-Z]`
- and that it must be at least 8 characters `{8,}`

This looks like a password requirements validator to me.

Strings it will match:

```
asdfsdklj2-3049-09AS
09809LK2JL23Lsdf
```

Strings it won't match:

```
asdfsdf
2398-02934
23Abs
```

As for your question about the dot (`.`): it's not a period, it's a regex special character that matches anything except newline. (In the regex101 explanation you can see it states `.{8,} matches any character (except newline)`). In this case, the reason `~"(.)".matches()` returns false, is because it requires a minimum of 8 characters in order to validate.

Comment: thanks for the response, I get as much. Why would the period be where it is in the regex? And why would ~"(.)".matches() return false for all strings?

Comment: That's not a period, it's a regex special character that matches anything except newline. In this case, the reason it's failing is because it requires a minimum of 8 characters in order to validate.

Comment: I change the regex according to some configuration. Say the regex becomes (.), well this fails. There is no length restriction in this. Do you know why this would be failing?

Comment: Put that into regex101 and you'll see exactly why. `(.)` is only ONE character, but it has no beginning or end string anchors (`^`, `$`). As such, it's effectively matching true for any/all characters. http://regex101.com/r/cE4tY2

Comment: Exactamundo, in the case where configuration has turned off all password validation, I'd want exactly that. But for some reason in groovy:

~".".matcher(<ANYSTRING>).matches() is returning false

Comment: Perhaps groovy is wrapping it in anchors? Try `.*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This checks to ensure the password contains a non-alphabetic character, that it contains at least one lowercase *and* uppercase alphabetic character, and finally that the entire string is at least 8 characters in length. The latter portion is where the `.` comes in – matching the entire string and ensuring it's 8+ characters.

Answer (score 0):

`(?=.*[^a-zA-Z)` - this checks that there is a non-alpha character somewhere in the password

`(?=.*[a-z])` - this checks that there is a lower case character in the password somewhere

`(?=.*[A-Z])` - this checks that there is an upper case character in the password somewhere

`.{8,}` - this checks that there are at least 8 characters.

?= is the positive lookahead.  The regex in this bracket must be matched and it must occur after this spot in the input.

Check [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) for all kinds of useful regex information and a quick reference that's very useful.

Comment: Oh all right, thanks! So the . is part of the legnth? Say there is no length restraint, will `((?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))` still do the other constraints?

Comment: `.` matches any character except for a newline; the `{8,}` means "8 or more times" and it's applied to the `.`.  You would still need `.+` in place of the `.{8,}`, the `+` meaning 1 or more times and being equivalent to `{1,}`.